# trying to install ros melodic on ubuntu 18.4, get broken packages error

Tags: ubuntu, ros

i've tried to follow official [instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) and run commands in console

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654

sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full

sudo apt-get install -f
```

got error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-melodic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-melodic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-melodic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Edit:
tried using `sudo aptitude install ros-melodic-desktop-full` it suggest to keep current version of 12 uninstalled packages

tried to upgrade apt, nothing changed

Comment: If you've just installed ubuntu, make sure to run `sudo apt update` first; not updating & upgrading the most frequent times I see this.

Comment: You could check: that `lsb_release -sc` returns 'bionic', that you're not using linux mint & calling it ubuntu, or any of these cmds to fix: `sudo apt update --fix-missing`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`; you could remove & reinstall via dpkg (all 3 cmds:) `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove --reinstreq`, `sudo apt clean`, `sudo apt update`. Beyond this, I'd say you should google/search for fixing broken packages more than it being a ros issue; it may be an issue you caused outside of ros. (But most commonly I've seen, as said, when forgetting to update).

Comment: couldn't run your last suggested chain of commands `dpkg: error:unknown force/refuse option remove''`

Comment: For that error, that's because you have to give it as an argument the broken pkg, and it doesn't recognize empty pkg ' '. I'd keep googling for fixing broken pkgs; there's a lot of material out there on this issue, and without more/better info it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: i already installed ros on another pc, thank you for your help tho.

Answer (score 0):

Although I removed and purged all ros-kinetic packages prior to upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to 18, I still encountered this problem.
in my case the issue was the conflicting python version which Ive installed on ubuntu 16 and got carried here.
first off purge all ros and gazebo packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge ros-*
sudo apt-get remove gazebo* catkin python-rospkg python-rospkg-modules
sudo rm -r /opt/ros/
sudo apt autoremove
```

then remove and install the python library:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa*
sudo apt remove libpython3.6-*
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

then restart and install the ros:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```